# Parameter value as attribute value

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to pass parameter value as value for attribute, but it uses parameter name as string value. Here is what I mean:

```
<CustomAction Id="TryToSetAsDefault" Property="CONFIG_XML_FILE_NAME" Value="config.xml"/>
...
<Component Id="cid" Guid="{...}" Permanent="yes">
   <File Id="fid" Name="[CONFIG_XML_FILE_NAME]" Source="$(var.SourceRoot)\config.xml"/>
</Component>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. The component names need to be set at build time and I don't think it can even take formatted values (using MSI Parameters). Can you elaborate on exactly why you are trying to do it this way and maybe there will be a better solution to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to make my installer create file named `config.xml` only if there is no existing file with such name in target directory, but if `config.xml` is already in the target directory, installer should create file named `template.xml`...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073405/wix-property-evaluation